# Awk calculation from 2 files piped paste -d

Tags: awk

The files contain: File1

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
...
```

-------------------File2

```
2 a
2 c
2 d
...
```

awk receives this format, seperated by comma:

```
1 a,2 a
2 b,2 c
...

paste -d, File1 File2 | awk -F, '{n=NF/2;s=""; for (i=1;i<=n;i++){printf "%s%s", s, ($i-$(i+n));s=",";}; print ""}'
```

I use this line to do a difference row by row of the first field; 
First row being  1-2 so prints -1

Ok it's all good I get the right answer, still I don't see how it can pick up the number field when the field is seperated by -F, representing

```
1 a
```

If I change

```
1 a
```

to

```
a 1
```

doing the same with the rest it doesn't work which I agree in logic.
So, in other words, how does it get the number when the field is the number and letter? $i = number, why not letter also?

Answer (score 2):

> how does it get the number when the field is the number and letter?

When `,` is your field separator (`-F,`), text like `2 a` is a single field, and it is simply treated as the number 2 when it is used as a number.

The AWK language is very permissive when you ask it to treat a string as a number. It reads the string until the point where it stops making sense as a number. At that point, if there was something that made sense, that's your number. Otherwise it takes it as 0. This all happens automatically when you use the string in an arithmetic expression. To see how it works, run:

```bash
awk '{print $0 + 0}'
```

`$0` is the whole line. Adding zero forces it to be interpreted as a number but doesn't change what number that is. Then you can type in lines of input to see how `awk` treats them as numbers. You will find, for example, that the empty string is 0, `3a` is 3, `1 2` is 1, `3.4.5.6` is 3.4, and so forth. (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line to signal end-of-input and quit `awk`, or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.)

---

Depending on what you actually want to do, you may be able to write a simpler command that is more clear about what it does and how it works, and that can be modified more easily. *For example*, if each file has just two columns separated by whitespace, and the entries do not themselves contain whitespace, just merge them into a four-column table by running `paste` without `-d` (or, if you prefer, with something like `-d ' '`) and process the table by piping it to `awk` without `-F`:

```bash
paste File1 File2 | awk '{print $1 - $3}'
```

Then it becomes obvious how you would adapt the AWK script when the numbers appear after the letters instead of before:

```bash
paste File3 File4 | awk '{print $2 - $4}'
```

(To test this, you can make `File3` and `File4` from `File1` and `File2`, respectively, by using `awk` to switch the columns. For example, `awk '{print $2, $1}' File1 > File3` makes `File3`.)

Comment: Thanks, it does explain why it works. Also, Knowing this I can see how to improve the syntax! It was not a copy/paste the FN was a typing error.